# A stored procedure that deletes all records using a lookup table IDs and a parameterised table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have fact tables with deleted records and a table called `IsDeletedRecords` that only contains deleted records, I want to run a stored procedure to eliminate the deleted records from all fact tables with lookup table Join and 'table' as a input parameter.

In the SQL statement below, I want to make `[tst].[bookableresource]` table name dynamic

```
DELETE a 
FROM [tst].[bookableresourcebooking] a
INNER JOIN [del].[IsDeleteIDs] b ON a.id = b.id 
                                 AND a = b.TableName
```

I would appreciate your help in defining the stored procedure.

I tried following but did not get the result;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteTableRows]  
    @TableName varchar (100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(256) = 'tst'
    DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SqlText = 'DELETE' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +  
                   'FROM' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + 
                   ' INNER JOIN [del].[IsDeleteIDs] b ON' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '.id = b.id'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlText
END
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: You're missing **spaces** after the `DELETE` and around the `FROM` keywords - right now, for a table `Customer`, you'd get `DELETECustomerFROMCustomer INNER JOIN....` ....

Comment: Help yourself to debugging the Dynamic Query by adding `PRINT @SqlText`

Comment: Looks like a bad idea. Why would you ever want this and not just have static procedures that do this? Perhaps you need to use Table Valued Parameters instead. There is also the injection risk.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach also looks right. Please use `select` statement to verify your query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteTableRows]  
    @TableName varchar (100) --[tst].[bookableresource]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(MAX) 

    SET @SqlText = 'DELETE FROM '+@TableName+ ' WHERE id in (select id from [del].[IsDeleteIDs] where TableName = '''+@TableName+''') ;'

    --select @SqlText
    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlText

    --Query executed
    --DELETE FROM [tst].[bookableresource] WHERE id in (select id from [del].[IsDeleteIDs] where TableName = '[tst].[bookableresource]') ;

END
```